# jQuery image width not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get image width of image with class product-thumbnail. There are several images with this width but all of them have the same width. So this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('img').('.product-thumbnail').width());
});
```

and these are image tags

```
<img src="img/produkt1.png" title="Názov produktu" class="product-thumbnail">
<img src="img/produkt2.png" title="Názov produktu" class="product-thumbnail">
```

however it doesnt work and I am not getting any alerts. There should be no problem with the selectors (jquery is included) and I want to use this so I can set div width acording to image width but the image width changes with browser windows width. Do you know a solution for this? Maybe I have only som syntax error there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that syntax. How does it differ from `alert($('img.product-thumbnail').width());`?

Comment: I have tried your syntax and it is working. Dont know why it didnt come to my mind (so easy) maybe I am just overworked. Post and answer if you want and I will accept it. Thanks for help

Comment: Using doc ready doesn't guarantee that your images have finished loading.

Comment: and what should I use instead?

Comment: window onload event or onload event of specific images

Comment: side question: can I use jquery resize() event listener to check when img size is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert($('img').('.product-thumbnail').width());
```

That is invalid jquery, the selector should all be inside the `$('')`, like a CSS selector, so it should be

```
alert($('img.product-thumbnail').width());
```

You also need to pick which image to get the width of, for the first one, you would do:

```
alert($('img.product-thumbnail')[0].width());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
alert($('img.product-thumbnail').width());
```

But even so, it's problematic since you will get an array back. In any case, the syntax you are using is wrong.